# Implementing Pseudo-Code for Multikey Sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, queue

The idea is to sort an list of objects which each hold two key values.

The pseudocode to preform such an algorithm was given to me like so:

```
To sort a list of objects with more than one key do
    for each key position P, Least significant to most significant key do
        Establish one queue for each of the key values
        For each object O in the list, do 
            place O in the queue corresponding to the key or O in position P
        end
   end 
end
```

I do not know how this translates to code, I'm having a hard time even understanding the psuedo code. 
But lets say I have this:

```
class main(){
sorter.build();
sorter.sort();
}


class sorter(){
public static ArrayList<lyrics> deck = new ArrayList<>();

public void build(){
//add.card objects to ArrayList deck
}

public void sort(){
// how do I begin the sort?
}


class card(){
public String suite;
public String rank;
public card(String s, String r){
suite = s;
rank = r;
}
```

Comment: You will get a more positive response here if you've show the code that's you've tried. I completely agree that the pseudocode here is tough, but it's not clear what part you're stuck on. Edit your question to include the code you've got by trying to translate it line by line.

Comment: Also, as a new user, make sure you check out [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask good, specific questions and avoid downvotes. If you provide necessary info, you'll get a better response here than from [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/2m8vl7/psuedo_code_to_real_code_has_me_flusteredjava/).

Comment: An example problem was put into code, but I do not understand the implications of the psuedo code, so I cannot be more specific than this. And I find that it is good to collect a wide range of answers, rather than just take one persons view on it and take it as gods word :) But I certainly appreciate your input, hopefully what I have provided is sufficient for the question.

Comment: I'm trying to write an answer for you, but honestly, this pesudocode is incomprehensible, imprecise, and lacking any sort of context. The way that you _should_ sort a list of multi-key objects in Java is by making the class implement the Comparable interface, and then write a compareTo method which compares two object (e.g. cards) based on the the key rankings.

Comment: Additionally, suite and rank shouldn't be `String` parameters. You should make both of those `enum` classes, where each valid element has a ranking via an [enum constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).